# Solving 4 unknowns with 4 equations all equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations:

$$\begin{align}
a&=0.35a+0.35d\\
b&=0.65a+0.65d\\
c&=0.35b+0.35c\\
d&=0.65b+0.65c
\end{align}$$

I know $b=d$, but where do I go from here?

I have a similar equation that I know the answer to, and I need to solve this one in the same way. The other question is:

$$\begin{align}
a&=0.8a+0.5c\\
b&=0.2a+0.5c\\
c&=0.5b+0.2d\\
d&=0.5b+0.8d
\end{align}$$

The answers to these equations are $a=d=\dfrac5{14}$ and $b=c=\dfrac2{14}$.

I don't know how to get there though.

Comment: How have you found $b=d$ and what else have you tried?

Comment: The two systems of equations you wrote are indetermined, i.e. they have not a unique solution. For example, you have the trivial solution $a=b=c=d=0$, which is not the solution you posted.

Comment: Worked it out now, they are probabilities so a+b+c+d=1   Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first equation: $0.65 a = 0.35 d$ (X), from third: $0.65c = 0.35 b$. Therefore (combining (X) with second equation) we have $b = d$. So the solution is

$$(a,b,c,d) = \left(\frac{7t}{13}, t,\frac{7t}{13},t \right), \quad t \in \mathbb R$$